# $x^a-(x-1)^a<c^a$

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

I work with math modelling and in one model I think it will be useful to solve the inequation

$$x^a-(x-1)^a<c^a,$$

with $0<c<1$ and $0<a<1$.

Do you have some hint? I need $x$ real, greater than $1$.

Thank you.

OBS.: (1) I need to iterate the solution for a lot of $a$'s (and a lot of $c$'s), so numerical solution is hard to work for many $c$′s. However, an aproximation for the solution would be OK!

(2) It would be ok if we consider $a\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What about $x$, it can be any?

Comment: @Vasili Edited, thank you!

Comment: Is a graphical solution considered deficient for some reason? This is transcendental.

Comment: @M.Reeves I need to iterate the solution for a lot of $a$, so numerical solution is hard to work for many $a's$. However, an aproximation for the solution would be OK!

Comment: @M.Reeves, it would be ok if we consider $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ if it matters.

Comment: Can you use calculus? Take a derivative and show that the maximum will be at $x=1$. However this inequality won't work for any $c$

Comment: @Vasili I disagree. You can prove that for some $b>1$, if $x>b$, this will always work. $f(x=1) > 0$, but $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x>1$. Intuitively, as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $f(x) \rightarrow -c^a < 0$. And $f(x) = x^a - (x-1)^a - c^a$.

Comment: @Paichu: Sure. I meant that it won't work for any $c$ and any $x>1$. Since the function is strictly decreasing, $b$ will be the solution of $f(x)=0$

Comment: @Vasili If you let $x\rightarrow\infty$, the LHS approaches $0$, while the RHS is always greater than $0$.

Comment: If you write the closed form for the integral of $(x^a - (x-1)^a - c^a)^2$, then you can search for the solution with binary search. Does that make sense? Or, if you prefer the reverse, use Newton's method. Not elegant, probably not what you're looking for. But if you're under time pressure, that will work.

Comment: @M.Reeves Yes, by now I am using Newton's method, but it's too expensive. If any analytical hint give me a "not so huge" $b$, with $b$ s.t. $b^a-(b-1)^a<c^a$ (I mean, a "not so bad" aproximation of $x^a-(x-1)^a=c^a$), it will be sufficient. By "not so bad", I mean, for instance, $O(x)$.

Comment: That could be simpler depending on $c$. Is it a true constant across all cases, or a given value that you sample many times? What is the PDF on this?

Comment: Also, you said for a given c you have to iterate a bunch of values for a. Since the LHS is monotonic on [1, $\infty$), you could save some time by using the solution $x$ for the previous value of $a$ as the starting point for your Newton's method search for the next value of $a$. . . . Should offer a speedup, assuming you can iterate over the values of $a$ in order. And since you know the derivative, you can generate a decent estimate of how far forward the solution moves given the difference between consecutive $a$ values.

Comment: I.e., if for your lowest value of $a$, $a_0$ you computed root $x_0$, and your next value $a_1$ is very close to $a_0$, you should start by guessing $x_1 = \frac{x_0^{a_0}\ln x_0 - (x_0-1)^{a_0}\ln (x_0-1)}{x_0^{a_0} - (x_0-1)^{a_0}}$.
Might even help if $a_0$ is not so close to $a_1$.

Comment: @M.Reeves The $c$ also changes through the iterations. But, I think I can take in mind your hints, many thanks!

Comment: @M.Reeves in fact, I have much more $c$'s than $a$'s. Do you have a hint about change the $c$ and mantain the $a$?

Comment: I would do the same thing w.r.t. the appropriate variable, finding $\frac {dx}{dc}$ and approximating Δx =dx and Δc = dc.

Comment: THank you @M.Reeves!

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $x^a$,
$$1-(1-1/x)^a<(c/x)^a.$$
For simplicity write this as equation for $y=1/x$,
$$
1<(1-y)^a+(cy)^a
$$

#### Solvability

The right side at $y=1$ has the value $c^a$. The right side can be considered as a weighted average, so we can apply the mean value inequality for the concave function $f(u)=u^a$ and some weight $w^a$ for the second term
\begin{align}
(1-y)^{a}+w^a·(cy/w)^{a}
&\le(1+w^a) \left(\frac{(1-y)+w^{a-1}·cy}{1+w^a}\right)^{a}
\\
&=(1+w^a)^{1-a} \left(1+(cw^{a-1}-1)·y\right)^{a}
\end{align}
With $w=c^{1/(1-a)}$ this gives a maximum value of $(1+w^a)^{1-a}>1$ at
$$
1-y_0=cy_0/w\iff 1=(1+c^{-a/(1-a)})y_0
$$
You can take $x_0=1+c^{-a/(1-a)}$ as one solution for the inequality.

#### Getting closer to the boundary

At $y\lessapprox 1$ the first term will rise quickly from zero as $a<1$ gives a vertical tangent. So it makes sense to linearize this term by raising it to the power $1/a$,
$$
1-y>\left(1-(cy)^a\right)^{1/a},
$$
or use the power directly as new variable, $z=(1-y)^a$, $y=1-z^{1/a}$,
$$
z>1-(c(1-z^{1/a}))^a
$$
The right side is a smooth function around $y=1$, so it can be approximated by its tangent.
\begin{align}
1-y&\approx\left(1-c^a[1-a(1-y)]\right)^{1/a}
\\
&\approx\left(1-c^a\right)^{1/a}\left[1+\frac{c^a(1-y)}{1-c^a}\right]
\\
y_1&= 1-\frac{(1-c^a)^{1/a}}{1-c^a(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}}
\\
x_1&=\frac{1-c^a(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}}{1-c^a(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}-(1-c^a)^{1/a}}
=\frac{1-c^a(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}}{1-(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}}
=\frac{1-c^a}{1-(1-c^a)^{1/a-1}}+c^a
\end{align}

This gives a value closer to the intersection point, but usually slightly violating the desired inequality.

Empirically, this approximation is insufficient if $a\ge \min(0.9,0.75·c+0.4)$. For these one would have to start with approximations that use that now $(1-a)$ is small.

---

One can refine even that using the fixed-point iteration $y=g(y)=1-(1-(cy)^a)^{1/a}$. This converges slowly,  so apply an acceleration method like Aitkens delta-squared method. Also, there are cancellation problems for small values of $a$ and $y\approx 1$, as then the small number $(1-(cy)^a)$ gets even more reduced under the power $1/a$.

Or apply the Newton or secant method to $f(y)=(1-y)^a+(cy)^a$. Use over-relaxation to more quickly find a point on the other side of the root.